Throw exception when putFile to Firebase Storage in background using WorkManager Flutter in IOS
I am encountering an issue with putFile in Firebase Storage when running in the background.
Everything works fine in the foreground, but it's not functioning in the background.
Please see the attached image. The problem arises at line 67.

my dependencies: in flutter 3.22.0
#firebase
firebase_core: ^3.1.0
firebase_analytics: any
firebase_crashlytics: ^4.0.1
firebase_storage: ^12.0.1
firebase_app_check: ^0.3.0+1
#run in background
workmanager:
git:
url: https://github.com/absar/flutter_workmanager.git
ref: ios-bg-tasks-enh-final
I check it's working in Android but not working in IOS

Did you check your firebase real time storage for image, when you upload file from your android device.

@Shivbaba'sson Android work exactly, but not working in IOS

appFile.name has extension of file like jpeg, png ?

@Shivbaba'sson yes, it has
